# Rails 3.2 session id nil until next request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

Trying to port a rails 2 app to rails 3, and I'm having some problems with sessions!

I can't seem to get a reference to the session id during the login phase.  I'm looking at both request.session_options and session, neither seem to be assigned the session id until the second request.

When the user logs in, i do session[:user_id] = user.id to put them in the session.  I looked in my session table, and it's definitely adding the session info there, but I want to be able to send the session id to the client, preferably with the login response.

It's worth noting, that on the next request that i send after login & the session is created, request.session_options does have good data, so it seems like things are happening, just not in the preferred order.

What's the best way to send back the session id with the login response?

Edit: The app I'm making is an external program talking to rails, so I can't really rely on browser cookies to automagically work.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this recently - see http://www.gani.com.au/2013/08/force-session-creation-in-rails/ . In the end I forced session creation by writing to it.

```
session[:foo] = 'bar'
```